# Динамическое позиционирование элеменетов

Tags: html, css, jquery

У меня есть картинка на заднем фоне блока

```
background-postion: center;
background-size: cover;
```

на ней есть элементы (на рисунке цифры) я хочу наложить на картинку несколько div так что бы они всегда были только на элементах самой картинки вне зависимости от ширины или высоты экрана. Я пытался давать div абсолютное позиционирование и толкать их в % но это не сработало.
[image: наброска позиционирования]

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал следующим образом с помощью jquery я узнаю какое разрешение экрана у пользователя 3:4 или 9:16, дальше я даю класс body если экран более квадратный то применяются одни стили а если нет то другие. Я тестировал на 5 полностью разных экран есть некоторое отличие но оно не критичное.